# How to keep me logged in with facebook connect on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facebook

Hey, I am using facebook connect sdk for iPhone, every time I start my app and click login, there would be a login screen asking me to input my name and password.

Is there any way to keep me logged in once I input my name and password, that's to say, I needn't to input my name and password again the next time I start my app?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Platform Guidelines 1.3, you are not allowed to store a Facebook user's credentials. The best you can hope for is that your user checks the "Keep me logged in" option. She should be able to post without having to login any time soon, even if she restarts your app.

The following snippet works with the above scenario:

```
NSString *fbAPIKey = ...;
NSString *fbApplicationSecret = ...;
_session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:fbAPIKey secret:fbApplicationSecret delegate:self] retain];

// checks whether session can be resumed - whether login is required
if (![_session resume]) {
    FBLoginDialog *loginDialog = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] initWithSession:_session] autorelease];
    [loginDialog show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the password (or the requisite hash of it) somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the keychain. Have a look to this article: http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, But the password and username are handled by Facebook Connect, I cant get it. It's a facebook standard login view, any idea that I can keep it as logged in?

Comment: Ho yes got it. You probably need to use [session resume]. The documentation says that the facebook session object is stored in the iPhone's preferences and can be reused later: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_for_iPhone#Logging_In